# How to pass $this to non-object function

Tags: php

When I pass `$this` to a function, I got error message like this, `The function does not exists.`

```
// In class A
class A extents F
{
    function m()
    { 
        Do($this);
    }

    function t()
    {
    }
}

class B extents F
{
    function m()
    { 
        Do($this);
    }

    function t()
    {

    }
}

// Some where in .inc.php file
function Do(F $obj)
{
    $obj->t();
}
```

Actually, I have many classes inherit from one base class. All those class have some functions in common. I need a function to deal them all.

Comment: replace `extents` with `extends`

Comment: You've got a few errors. For instance, PHP does not support type-hinting (`Do(F $obj)` is not right, should be `Do($obj)`).

Comment: also, did you try removing the F class requirement for the Do function? because if you don't have the t() method in your abstract class then I think that it might be the problem.

Comment: @JaredFarrish PHP do support type hinting afaik

Comment: @Jared: PHP does support object type hints: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Comment: @Manhim - Wow, how did I miss that?

Comment: @Tomasz - Wow, how did I miss that?

Comment: It's not commonly used - I'm quite a PHP enthusiast and many times read documentation for fun, so i know. It's especially useful in PHP 5.3 world, when using namespaces. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `Do()` as a function name because it's [reserved word](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.php)

Also, you can't use `extents` because it's `extends`

Also, you can't use `extends F` because you have no class F there

This one works

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/450ee/1

```
<?php
class F{

}
class A extends F
{
    function m()
    { 
        _Do($this);
    }

    function t()
    {
        echo "<br />Class A works";
    }
}

//removed unused class B
$a = new A();
$a->m();

// Some where in .inc.php file
// Changed Do to _Do, because Do is reserved word
function _Do(A $obj)
{
    $obj->t();
}
```

Comment: @hakre: Isn't your edit just some kind of description, comment what $obj should contain?

Comment: Well as you call `t()` later on, it's actually a pre-condition, so much more than a comment.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen: Really? Look [here](http://codepad.org/qSR7TcyS) and you'll see that doesn't matter [in this case]

Comment: @Michael Madsen: Not with the T_DO token.